# Behavior flow in Google analytics. How to filter on specific domain under cross domain tracking?

Tags: google-analytics

Does anyone know how to filter the "behavior flow" on specific domains under cross domain tracking?

Today we have a lots of clients we track and therefore the flow is jumping between the different subdomains.

On other views in Google analytics you can easily put a filter on a specific page:
[image: Screenshot of advanced filter in full report views]

I know there is an option for selecting "Pages and Events" in a drop down menu, where you can select some of the specific pages, but this list is auto generated to just some of the popular landing sites under the sub domains.

Comment: Create a segment by hostname, this can also be applied to flow views. However this might be off topic for SO and better suited for the webmasters.stackexchange site as it's not about code but about configuration.

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to move the question?